# DiscretePlot of a function containing Nintegrate under Sum

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, warning-messages, summation

I am trying to get `DiscretePlot` of the following integral containing laguerre polynomial, the Mathematica code of which is given below:

```
A1[l0_, ρ_, n_, m_, q_, h_, M_, 
  v_] := (Sqrt[(2*(q - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l0^2*q!)])*
  Exp[-((I/(2*h)*M*v*ρ^2)/l0)]*
  Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l0^2))]*((ρ^2/l0^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[q - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l0^2)]*(Sqrt[(2*(n - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l0^2*n!)])*
  Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l0^2))]*((ρ^2/l0^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[n - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l0^2)]*ρ
E0[q_, m_, w0_, Ω_, 
  h_] := (q + 1/2)*h*(w0 + Ω) + (q - m + 1/2)*
   h (w0 - Ω) + (4 + 1/2)*h*10
p1[l0_, l1_, ρ_, n1_, m_, q_, h_, M_, v_, 
  w0_, Ω_, τ_] := (Sqrt[(
   2*(n1 - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l1^2*n1!)])*
  Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l1^2))]*((ρ^2/l1^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[n1 - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l1^2)]*(Sqrt[(2*(q - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l1^2*q!)])*
  Exp[(I/(2*h)*M*v*ρ^2 - 
    I/h*l0*E0[q, m, w0, Ω, h]*τ)/l1]*
  Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l1^2))]*((ρ^2/l1^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[q - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l1^2)]*ρ
p2[n_, q_] := 
 NIntegrate[A1[1, ρ, n, 1, q, 1, 1, 5], {ρ, 0, Infinity}]*
  NIntegrate[
   p1[1, 2, ρ, 2, 1, q, 1, 1, 5, 10, 5, 10], {ρ, 0, 
    Infinity}]
p3[n_] := Sum[p2[n, q], {q, 1, 10}]
DiscretePlot[Abs[p3[n]]^2, {n, 1, 6, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

But it shows the following error:

```
NIntegrate::errprec: Catastrophic loss of precision in the global error estimate due to insufficient WorkingPrecision or divergent integral.
```

I searched in the already discussed question in Mathematica stack exchange related to this kind of error and I got a particular case under heading "Catastrophic loss of precision", where it is suggested to avoid the error by using `Table` command, but I could not follow the same properly in my case.

Would you kindly suggest me how to amend my code such that I can get the desired plot?

Comment: Maybe you should focus on which call to `NIntegrate` causes the error. Alternatively, the message is implying you should try increasing `WorkingPrecision`. (`Table` seems an unlikely fix, though the separate integrals would be returned instead of their sum. That might be helpful.)

Comment: Also, [using `?NumericQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) on the arguments of `p2[]`, while it probably won't fix this problem, is good practice.

Comment: Sir, thanks for your kind response...It sppears to me on going through your valuable comments that the order of operation matters...i.e. 2 input indexes such as n and q should be specified maintaining the order....Sir, if you dont mind, would you kindly show me the ameneded code of p2[n_,q_] inserting ?NumericQ

Comment: `p2[n_?NumericQ,q_?NumericQ] := <..rest of definition..>` is how it is shown in the "Applications" section of the `NumericQ` documentation and the examples in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Sir, I have written the same thing but still it does not show anything.. `p2[n_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[A1[1, \[Rho], n, 1, q, 1, 1, 5], {\[Rho], 0, Infinity}]*
  NIntegrate[
   p1[1, 2, \[Rho], 2, 1, q, 1, 1, 5, 10, 5, 10], {\[Rho], 0, 
    Infinity}]p3[n_?NumericQ] := Sum[p2[n?NumericQ, q?NumericQ], {q, 1, 10}]DiscretePlot[Abs[p3[n?NumericQ]]^2, {n, 1, 6, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red]`

Comment: (1) You seemed to have added `?NumericQ` in more than the two places I indicated. (2) What does not show anything? (You said "it.") I did say I didn't think this would solve the problem with your code. To do that, you'll have to fix the `NIntegrate` call that gives the error. Have you determined which on that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NIntegrate has problems, because integrand is highly osccilatroy.

But this can all be done with Integrate in 8 seconds.

```
A1[l0_, \[Rho]_, n_, m_, q_, h_, M_, 
  v_] := (Sqrt[(2*(q - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l0^2*q!)])*
  Exp[-((I/(2*h)*M*v*\[Rho]^2)/l0)]*
  Exp[-(\[Rho]^2/(2*l0^2))]*((\[Rho]^2/l0^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[q - (Abs[m] + m)/2, 
   Abs[m], (\[Rho]^2/
     l0^2)]*(Sqrt[(2*(n - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l0^2*n!)])*
  Exp[-(\[Rho]^2/(2*l0^2))]*((\[Rho]^2/l0^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[n - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (\[Rho]^2/l0^2)]*\[Rho]
E0[q_, m_, w0_, \[CapitalOmega]_, 
  h_] := (q + 1/2)*h*(w0 + \[CapitalOmega]) + (q - m + 1/2)*
   h (w0 - \[CapitalOmega]) + (4 + 1/2)*h*10
p1[l0_, l1_, \[Rho]_, n1_, m_, q_, h_, M_, v_, 
  w0_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Tau]_] := (Sqrt[(2*(n1 - (Abs[m] + m)/
           2)!)/(l1^2*n1!)])*
  Exp[-(\[Rho]^2/(2*l1^2))]*((\[Rho]^2/l1^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[n1 - (Abs[m] + m)/2, 
   Abs[m], (\[Rho]^2/
     l1^2)]*(Sqrt[(2*(q - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l1^2*q!)])*
  Exp[(I/(2*h)*M*v*\[Rho]^2 - 
      I/h*l0*E0[q, m, w0, \[CapitalOmega], h]*\[Tau])/l1]*
  Exp[-(\[Rho]^2/(2*l1^2))]*((\[Rho]^2/l1^2)^(Abs[m]/2))*
  LaguerreL[q - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (\[Rho]^2/l1^2)]*\[Rho]
p2[n_, q_] := 
 Integrate[A1[1, \[Rho], n, 1, q, 1, 1, 5], {\[Rho], 0, Infinity}]*
  Integrate[
   p1[1, 2, \[Rho], 2, 1, q, 1, 1, 5, 10, 5, 10], {\[Rho], 0, 
    Infinity}]
p3[n_] := Sum[p2[n, q], {q, 1, 10}]
(tab = Table[Abs[p3[n]]^2, {n, 1, 6}]; tab // N) // AbsoluteTiming

(*   {8.2475393, {0.000440122, 0.000138649, 0.00142201, 0.00274115, 
  0.00326648, 0.0031438}}   *)
```

Comment: Thank you, Sir... for your kind response...Yes, I have also done the same thing using Integrate instead of NIntegrate..Actually, Sir MicaelE2 pointed out the same thing that somehow NIntegarte created the problem....Thank you once again Sir...